# How can I set up disk quotas on a remote server in a Samba environment?

Tags: samba, cifs, quota

I've been working with an install of Ubuntu 8.04 and Samba.

I'm trying to set up user disk space quotas for our shared drive.  That is, each user will have their own folder on our Network Attached Storage (NAS) that has a size limit. I can successfully mount the shared drive, but I can't figure out how to set quotas on it (I think smbcquota might work, but I'm not sure).

It's been suggested to me to give each user a share on the shared drive or to use NFS. Unfortunately, neither option works for my purposes.

Does anyone know how I could give users a quota on my NAS?

Comment: what NAS device are you using?

Comment: I'm using a Buffalo Linkstation.  However it doesn't seem to support quotas, so I'm hoping that quotas can be enforced by Samba in some way or another.

Answer (score 2):

For Samba to support quotas, there must be few preconditions met:
Samba must be compiled with quota support, the FS being shared must support quotas *and* have the quotas enabled.

To turn on quotas you need to:

1. Add `usrjquota=aquota.user,jqfmt=vfsv0` to mount options in `/etc/fstab` and create a `aquota.user` file in root directory of file system (if it's a `/home` FS, you can create it using `touch /home/aquota.user`.
2. Re-calculate current disk usage with

   ```
   quotacheck -vguma
   ```

To set the quotas you may use either `quotactl`, `quota` and similar Linux tools *or* connect to the share as **root** (no other user will work, including the ones defined in `admin users`) and use the windows share properties to change quotas.

Answer (score 0):

I think that googling would have helped you. Try using this tutorial

http://portfolio.itas.ca/~schewet/257T/mini3.html

and check-out Samba SWAT

Comment: Thanks for the link, but I'd already read it.  The problem with that tutorial is that it applies to local file systems (in their case ext3).  I need something for CIFS.  This is what my entry in fstabs looks like:

\\linkstation\share  /media/share  cifs  workgroup=DLLAB,fmask=777,uid=1002,ip=192.168.1.4,dmask=777,usrquota,credentials=/etc/.credentials  0  0

The GUI that I'm working with can be found here:
http://www.turnkeylinux.org/domain-controller

Comment: \\linkstation\share /media/share cifs workgroup=DLLAB,fmask=777,uid=1002,ip=192.168.1.4,dmask=777,usrquota,credentials=/etc/.credentials 0 0

Answer (score 0):

From what I've learned, what I want is not possible.  If my NAS supported NFS or if it supported quotas locally, I could probably get it to work.